# How to keep the metadata along with the picture

Tags: png, jpeg, photo

I've been scanning some old family photos and posting them to Facebook. On the back is some information like the date or who is in the photo.  So I'm dutifully entering that info into Facebook as well.  But now the metadata is in Facebook, not connected to the picture itself.

If I copy/paste my scanned images subfolder, there's no metadata about who or when these pictures are from.

Is there a way to embed that info into a jpg or png?

Comment: It looks like in the details property there is a title, subject, rating stars, tags and comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this in both PNG and JPEG. The simplest way in JPEG is to inset a COMment marker with your text into the stream. You could do that with a simple C program without having to recompress the data. Just insert the comment marker after the SOF and APPn marker---it could even be write before the EOI (end of image) marker).

Some JPEG file formats (e.g. EXIF) have various predefined tags but that is format specific.

For that you'd need some image viewing application that would allow you to set the tag values.